# Grow parent to width of the child

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a child element inside of a parent element. The child has a min-width set, which makes it (at some screen sizes) wider than the parent element. The child's width correctly is set to the min-width, but the parent's width seems to max out at the original screen width. I would like the parent to grow with the child. How can I achieve this?

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: auto;
}

.grid {
  min-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: start;
}

.grid > div { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the example, 'container' (blue background) is narrower than the child 'grid' (the grid of yellow boxes). If you scroll right, you can see that the blue background stops at the edge of the screen, while the yellow grid continues. I would like the blue area to grow to contain the child grid.

I have tried setting `width` and `min-width` properties on the container to auto and/or 100%. I've also tried changing the display to inner-block. None of these work.

Comment: display:inline-block;min-width:100%; has better support than fit-content

Comment: @TemaniAfif ~ It may have better support, but it was also one of the things I tried first which didn't work. Perhaps there's something else on my page which was interfering with it, but the `fit-content` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `width: fit-content` on the `.container` element would allow it to expand outside of the window bounds when necessary.

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  width: fit-content;
}

.grid {
  min-width: 1000px;
  display: grid;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, auto);
  
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  align-items: start;
}

.grid > div { 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
    <div>D</div>
    <div>E</div>
    <div>F</div>
    <div>G</div>
  </div>
</div>
```